# String Concatenation error in Cygwin bash shell

Tags: cygwin, concatenation

I am having problems concatenate two strings in BASH (I am using Cygwin)

When I am doing it step by step in the cygwin window, it works.

i.e by defining `dt=2012-12-31` and `c=.txt` explicitly and then concatenating in `filename=${dt}${c}`.

It doesn't seem to work when I am running it through my script where these variables are defined by cutting and assigning values from content of a file.

Though the variables are assigned with the same values as above, the concatenation in this case doesn't work.

Instead of `2012-12-31.txt` I am getting `.txt-12-31` as result.

The code is:

```
for x in {0..11}
do
    IFS=$'\n'
    filename=date_list.txt
    file=($(<"$filename"))
    IFS=$'\t\n'
    dt=${file[$x]}
    echo $dt

for y in {0..85}
do  
    IFS=$'\n'
    filename=SQL_Mnemonics.txt
    file=($(<"$filename"))
    IFS=$'\t\n'
    Mn=${file[$y]}
    
        for k in {3..502}
        do
            IFS=$'\n'
            c=.txt
            filename=${dt}${c}
            file=($(<"$filename"))
            IFS=$'\t\n'
            echo ${file[$k]} > temp_file.txt
            cusip=`cut -c11-19 temp_file.txt`
            result=$(sh ctest.sh $Mn, $dt, $cusip)
            echo "$result" > tmp1.txt
            t1=`cut -c18-40 tmp1.txt`
            echo $t1 | sed 's/[[:space:]]//g' > temp_file.txt
            cat tst.txt | sed 's/-----//g' >> ForFame/${Mn}.${dt}.txt
        done
done
done
```

Comment: We need to see the code.

Comment: added the code .. thnx fr the prompt reply

Comment: got it ....did DOS2Unix to date_list.txt ...

Comment: @user2183638, what did you do? Having same issue.